# OpenID Backchannel Logout contains no Logout Token

Tags: single-sign-on, openid, identityserver4, identityserver3

I am trying to implement Single-Sign-Out procedure within my clients and Identity Provider (Identity Server 4). I managed to set correctly an *Iframe* page that gets rendered whenever a user logs out (either from the Identity Server itself or from a client). Such rendering triggers the call of the **endsession** endpoint, which is an internal mechanism of Identity Server that calls all the clients who have a **BackChannelLogoutUri** registered. My client receives the call from Identity Server (it's a POST call) but unfortunately the call is not authenticated.

[image]

This causes a redirect in my client due to a non authorized call.
At the same time I cannot really debug what's happening in this **endsession** endpoint of Identity Server. Any tips by any chance on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on your `POST` action for single sign out in your client application. The user in this case is validated not by cookie, but by the `logout_token` that Identity Server passes in the `POST` call.